# Setting up REST post request

Tags: 8

I am having issues sending a POST request to create a node with Drupal 8 Core REST. Here are the steps I have went through several times. Note that these steps are in effort to produce a working example, I am not worried about the security implications as of yet.

1. Install latest version of drupal 8
2. Enable all core web services modules (HAL, HTTP Basic Authentication, RESTful Web Services, Serialization)
3. Go to permissions page. Find RESTful Web Services permissions and allow delete, get, patch, and post for all users. Find Node Article permissions, allow create, delete and edit for all users.
4. Launch Dev HTTP Client in Chrome. Input the following request:

[image]
After hitting Send, I receive the following message which I believe should be a 201 and not a 200 if a node were to successfully be created. I think the REST part is working, its just I cant seem to figure out how to get POST to create a node.

[image]

I am having trouble finding any documentation on making post requests to Drupal 8 REST. Insight into how to construct these requests so that Drupal can parse them successfully would be very helpful.

Comment: When I was fiddling with D8 REST I had to change the hal+json to json in some configuration file and then it started to work. I was never able to get hal+json format working.

Comment: do you recall what file it was you edited? did you edit it preinstallation or postinstallation? Did it result in being able to create nodes? If so what would a POST request to create an article look like?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2076725

Comment: I forked original module and fixed this bug and pull request. I hope accept this branch.
You can download it in https://github.com/setali/drupal_cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the solution on the (identical) issue on drupal.org:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2472451#comment-9903259
Also see the Dev HTTP Client screenshot attached in that comment.

Basically there are a couple of things wrong in your example:

- endpoint is /entity/node
- add Accept header "application/json"
- add CSRF token (which can be requested via /rest/session/token)

Comment: just got the 201 from your instructions. thank you.

Comment: Accept headers are no longer used: https://www.drupal.org/node/2501221 - Instead use `?_format=json` in the query string for the URL.

Comment: I tried the very same thing but, returns 415

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein I thought post requests only accepted hal+json

Answer (score 6):

As I still ran into a lot of 403 errors, I'll summarize my overall solution (Drupal 8.0.1).

### Setup and configuration

Enable all core web services modules (HAL, HTTP Basic Authentication, RESTful Web Services, Serialization). Enable the relevant permissions of RESTful Web Services and for creating the relevant Nodes.

### Get a CSRF token

`GET http://your-drupal8/rest/session/token`

### POST to create a new node

`POST http://your-drupal8/entity/node?_format=hal+json`

Note that the URL for POST seems to be /entity/node rather than /node.

#### Headers

```
Authorization: Basic QWRt...
X-CSRF-Token: zCf...
```

#### Data

```
{
"title": [
  { "value": "atest2" }
],
"type": [
  { "target_id": "article" }
],
"_links": {
  "type": { "href": "http://your-drupal8/rest/type/node/article" }
}
}
```

Comment: Couples question: 1) Do you need an authorization header if you allow anonymous users to create articles and perform post requests? 2) Don't you need a 'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json' in the header as well?

Comment: I've been trying to sort this out for ages and this still does not work for my local dev site. I have enabled *|* on CORS, allowed GET & POST for content in the REST-UI and I keep getting a 500. Any ideas what else could be required?

Comment: How do you get the value for the `Authorization` header? I thought Basic meant you pass in `username:password` as the value.